# Subtracting numbers, result should be 0, but getting some strange exponential numbers

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm pretty new here...

I have a (simple, hopefully) problem.  I am taking a column (a) and subtracting from it columns (x,y,z) and the result SHOULD be 0.

Some are 0 as expected, but on some others I get exponential numbers, but they should be 0... any idea what could be causing this? or how to fix it?  floor?...

Comment: You probably got something like 1.2E-34. The negative number after the E means it's 1.2*10^(-34) which is as close to zero as matters.

Comment: Any idea why I would get these types of numbers though?  It is on simple subtraction, so it seems that I should get 0.

Comment: you should add the code you are using to the question, together with some sample data that would give the result you are getting and the results from executing the code on the sample data.

Comment: Added sql and example

Comment: Thanks for adding that formatting!!!!

Comment: I think this page (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm) could useful. Depending on your data you can just round the result ( i = round(i,.1); )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems